# Regex or java solution for parsing this string

Tags: java, android, regex, parsing

I am entering the command `show vlan` and receiving data in this format, it is one string:

```
switch# show vlan
VLAN Name                             Status    Ports                           
---- -------------------------------- --------- ------------------------------- 
1    default                          Active    Fa1/0, Fa1/1, Fa1/4, Fa1/6      
                                                Fa1/7, Fa1/8, Fa1/9, Fa1/10     
                                                Fa1/11, Gi0                     
2    VLAN0002                         Active                                    
3    VLAN0003                         Active    Fa1/5                           
6    VLAN0006                         Active                                    
999  VLAN0999                         Active    Fa1/2, Fa1/3
switch#
```

I wish to make new strings that start with the number of the vlan and end when it reaches the VLAN number. So the Strings here would be:

```
(1)    1    default                          Active    Fa1/0, Fa1/1, Fa1/4, Fa1/6      
                                                       Fa1/7, Fa1/8, Fa1/9, Fa1/10     
                                                       Fa1/11, Gi0                     
(2)    2    VLAN0002                         Active                                    
(3)    3    VLAN0003                         Active    Fa1/5                           
(4)    6    VLAN0006                         Active                                    
(5)    999  VLAN0999                         Active    Fa1/2, Fa1/3
```

What would I do here, a regex that tests for a number followed by a white space but with a \r or \n before it? Or similar in java using .charAt(i) etc? and then substring it?

The I need to split each of these strings into tokens with a white space delimiter. I would use a for loop to go through each string I guess.

I tried splitting at \r\n if it is followed by a digit, was this right?

```
String[] parts = finalCommand.split("\r\n?=\\d");
```

but it doesn't work?! I really can't see why.

Comment: That seems to be a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14650946/how-to-parse-text-from-multiple-strings

Comment: Nah I made that and solved it on my own. That question was how to form the string I now want to split, which was quite annoying to do in the end.

Comment: Isn't what you want just a simple `String.split` and then formatting the lines that starts with numbers?

Comment: If I do a string.split there are lines like this: "                                                 Fa1/7, Fa1/8, Fa1/9, Fa1/10 " that are just loads of whitespace and then some numbners I need. Then i have to append them to the string I want.

Comment: Also split does not keep the delimiter. Maybe I can make it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I tried splitting at \r\n if it is followed by a digit, was this right?
>
> ```
> String[] parts = finalCommand.split("\r\n?=\\d");
> ```
>
> but it doesn't work?! I really can't see why.

If `finalCommand` is after you've already stripped off the leading `#switch\r\n` and trailing `\r\nswitch#`, and if the lines in `finalCommand` are indeed separated by `\r\n`, then — yes, that's *almost* right. The only thing you need to change is, you need to write `(?=\d)` rather than `?=\d`: the parentheses are part of the syntax for a lookahead assertion. (Otherwise `\n?=` is interpreted as "an optional `\n`, followed by `=`.) So:

```
String[] parts = finalCommand.split("\r\n(?=\\d)");
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `split()` is the tool you're looking for.  Check this out:

```
List<String> matchList = new ArrayList<String>();
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("(?m)^\\d+.*$(?:\r?\n(?!\\S).*$)*");
Matcher m = p.matcher(s);
while (m.find()) {
    matchList.add(m.group());
}
```

As you said, continuation lines are characterized by whitespace following the line separator.  This regex identifies them by doing a negative lookahead for a non-whitespace character (`\S`) immediately after the line separator.

The `(?m)` turns on multiline mode, allowing `^` and `$` to match the beginning and end of individual lines.  Note that it's the *carriage return* (`\r`) that's optional in the line separator, not the linefeed (`\n`).

Comment: Thanks, good answer, I wish I could accept both. I don't really understand the fully regex yet though :) (?m) means the following regex is applied to multiple lines? then ^\\d starts with a digit. + is one or more numbers, then anything any number of times?  Does teh ?: make the \r optional? then you look ahead for a non whitespace with ?!. why the .* then? Is it needed to say anything can follow? and the * at the end does it multiple times?

Answer (score 0):

Answer was pretty simple, was some sort of brackets problem

This doesn't work:

```
String[] parts = finalCommand.split("\r\n?=\\d");
```

This does:

```
String[] parts = finalCommand.split("(\r\n)(?=\\d)");
```